# Stuck trying to decompress sections in Minecraft Anvil files (.mca)

Tags: java, minecraft-modding

I've been trying to write some Java code to read .mca files, based on the information at http://wiki.vg/Map_Format and http://wiki.vg/User:Sprenger120 . I am at the point where I can read in the header correctly, and read the header for each section, telling me its compression mode and size. I am now trying to inflate the NBT blob that is the actual section, but it's not working at all. I just get "java.io.IOException: Not in GZIP format".

I'm starting the deflation stream five bytes into the memory segment specified by the header, and given that I am consistently getting sane section sizes and compression types, it seems like I'm managing to parse correctly up to this point, but now I'm stuck.

The code is at: https://github.com/Zarkonnen/Ager/tree/master/src/ager

I don't know if this is the correct forum to ask this kind of question - if it isn't, I apologise and would be very thankful if someone could direct me to a good place to ask it.

Comment: Your github link is a 404. You pasted a URL that actually has ... in it.

Comment: So the 5th byte of the data header is a 1 for the file you are parsing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so the immediate answer to this turns out to be that JNBT internally tries to decompress the stream using GZIP, so I was decompressing it twice.

In the end, the better way of going about it was to use the code supplied by Mojang at http://www.mojang.com/2012/02/new-minecraft-map-format-anvil/ .